# SED regex syntax from notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, sed, notepad++

this is my first question here ;)

I have query in notepad++ - i want to search specific string between two others. I need do replace this string with ie. xxxxxxxxxx, i'm searchig for:

```
<f n='foobar'><v>84093055983</v></f>
```

should look in this way:

```
<f n='foobar'><v>xxxxxxxxxxx</v></f>
```

The number between `<v>` tags are allways different, the rest is allways the same. 
Query looks like this: `(?<=(foobar'><v>))(\d{11})(.*?)(?=<)`

I need to run about 20 search&replace for one file, i think, that somekind of script shoud be fine, but notepad++ aint have such functionality - i found a SED (i use windows, so SED is from CYGWIN).

I'v tried few different approches, but i can't figure out, how this should look in SED.

Or do U know any fine way to do this? ;p

Comment: `sed 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/' FILENAME` is the basic syntax for regex substitutions using `sed`. Just replace the placeholders in capital letters with the real strings.

Comment: Try -r option for extended regex

Comment: Must all numbers be replaced by the same string (ie `xxxxxxxxxxx`)?

Answer (score 1):

Use somthing like `sed -r "s#(f n='foobar'><v>)\d{11}(</v></f>)#\1xxxxxxxxxxx\2#g" inflile > outfile` or use the `-i` option of gnu sed .

I use `s#PATTERN#REPLACEMENT#` with `#` instead of `/`, because your search string has slashes in it.

Comment: Thanks ;) Works fine with: `s#(<f n='foobar'><v>).*?(</v></f>)#\1xxxxxxxxxxx\2#g;`. Now i'm trying to replace `.*?` with something like this, but, for now it wont work: `[[:digit:]]\{11\}`

Comment: @Fangir For me this works: `echo "<f n='foobar'><v>84093055983</v></f>" | sed -r "s#(f n='foobar'><v>)[[:digit:]]{11}(</v></f>)#\1xxxxxxxxxxx\2#g"` (option `-r` and plain `{11}` without backslash).